# ¿Cómo obtener los penúltimos registros de un grupo MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, filtro

¿Cómo puedo obtener los penúltimos registros de un grupo en MySQL?

Tengo una tabla llamada "tabla_deposito" con 4 columnas (id, usuario, fecha_deposito, monto_depositado), y quiero agrupar por la columna usuarios y que me seleccione el penúltimo registro de cada usuario.

id|usuario|fecha_deposito|monto_depositado

```
1 | user1 | 01/01/19 | 1000
2 | user2 | 01/01/19 | 500
3 | user3 | 01/01/19 | 400
4 | user2 | 02/02/19 | 3500
5 | user1 | 02/02/19 | 100
6 | user3 | 02/02/19 | 50
```

como resultado quiero algo así, agrupar por usuarios y seleccionando los penúltimos registros y descartar los últimos registros.

Me imagino que se hace por id o por fecha el filtrado. seleccionando el ultimo y restando 1. ejemplo:

```
id|usuario|fecha_deposito|monto_depositado
1 | user1 | 01/01/19 | 1000
2 | user2 | 01/01/19 | 500
3 | user3 | 01/01/19 | 400
```

Coloqué 6 registros de ejemplo pero son muchos mas. yo lo que quiero es agrupar por usuario y que me seleccione el penúltimo registro de cada usuario y lo muestre en una consulta.

Ejemplo: si hay 10 usuarios registrados con n cantidad de depósitos entonces que me muestre los 10 usuarios con el penúltimo deposito que realizo cada usuario.

ya he probado LIMIT, pero no me da la selección que estoy buscando porque solo me toma el penúltimo pero de un solo usuario y yo necesito es de todos los usuarios que están agrupados con group by usuarios.

Comment: Utliza el LIMIT, por ejemplo LIMIT 10,40

Comment: gracias por comentar, lo he realizado pero no me sale. si puede poner un ejemplo de la consulta le agradezco.

Comment: yo la realice con LIMIT 1 pero solo me selecciona 1 solo registro. yo necesito es el penúltimo registro de cada usuario.

Comment: @mack, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la definición de la estructura de la tabla `deposito`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo así debería servirte...

```
SELECT (
    SELECT td_aux.id
    FROM tabla_deposito AS td_aux
    WHERE td_aux.usuario = td.usuario
    ORDER BY td_aux.fecha_deposito DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
) AS id,
td.usuario,
(
    SELECT td_aux.fecha_deposito
    FROM tabla_deposito AS td_aux
    WHERE td_aux.usuario = td.usuario
    ORDER BY td_aux.fecha_deposito DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
) AS fecha_deposito,
(
    SELECT td_aux.monto_depositado
    FROM tabla_deposito AS td_aux
    WHERE td_aux.usuario = td.usuario
    ORDER BY td_aux.fecha_deposito DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
) AS monto_depositado
FROM tabla_deposito AS td
GROUP BY td.usuario
```

Comment: Excelente!!, esta es la solución a mi consulta, muy agradecido con usted y con todos los que dedicaron su tiempo en ayudar. mil gracias para todos.

Answer (score 0):

Te explico, no quería ponerlo como solución, por que seguro que hay una forma mejor.
Son 2 query's.

1. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA` esto nos devuelve en numero de registros que tiene la tabla. Como tu quieres el penultimo le restamos 2.

Por ejemplo: si sale 36 pues quedara en 34.

Guardamos este numero.

2. `SELECT NOMBRE, CANTIDAD FROM TABLA LIMIT 34, 1`

Esta query descarta el ultimo registro.

Espero que te sirva de algo. Suerte.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, pero creo que no me estas entendiendo el ejemplo, yo lo realizo de esa manera como me estas indicando pero solo me toma un solo registro. lo que quiero es agrupar por columna de usuarios group by usuarios.. y que me seleccione el penúltimo registro de la columna deposito... ejemplo: me muestre el penúltimo deposito que realizo cada usuario.. otro ejemplo para ver si me entiendes: si tengo 10 usuarios con 5 depósitos por cada usuario, quiero que me muestre los 10 usuarios con el penúltimo deposito realizado.

Comment: Pues lo siento mucho, no te entendí bien, para este caso, solo se me ocurre hacer un procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: gracias. esperare otra solución. :(

Answer (score 0):

Debes seleccionar el máximo `id` y agrupar por `usuario`:

```
SELECT MAX(id), usuario, fecha_deposito,depositado 
FROM tabla 
GROUP BY usuario
```

Comment: saludos, gracias por comentar, esa consulta me trae los ultimos registros pero yo necesito son los penultimos registros.. lo he intentado de muchas formas incluyento LIMIT, pero no funciona lo que realmente necesito. les agradezco si me ayudan. muchas gracias